# Looking for Windows utility to find a pixel of specific color on screen

Tags: colors

I need to find pixels of specific RGB color on my computer screen quickly. Something like pressing a hot key and the mouse cursor is moved to there or the area is circled.

I would prefer a Windows utility that works on the screen directly but if it works on a saved screenshot, I can live with that.

Comment: May we ask why you need that ?

Comment: Can't go into details but it's related to testing a special watermarking algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange question.

You can write a script for that in photoshop (select by color, grow selection, then paint selection). Then assign it to a shortcut, let's say F5.

Then press print screen (takes a snapshot)
Go to photoshop
CTRL+N > new document (it will have the dimension of the image in paperclip)
enter
CTRL+V > paste image
F5 > run the script